# docker-compose for Spring Boot and MySQL showing error: failed to receive status: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a docker compose consisting of Spring Boot and MySQL. But when docker comes to building Spring Boot, I'm getting `failed to receive status: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF`

Here's my Spring Boot project structure and application.properties file:
[image: img]

**application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
server.address=0.0.0.0
```

I got from somewhere that environment variables from docker-compose.yml will replace application.properties variables so I left it like this when making the aifarming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar file by maven package.

Also here's my **Dockerfile** and **docker-compose.yml** file.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/home/app/target/aifarming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  spring-boot-container:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9090:8080    # Map port 9090 on the host to port 9090 in the container
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-container:3307/world
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO: update
      SPRING_JPA_SHOW-SQL: "true"
      SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
      SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL: "true"
    depends_on:
      - mysql-container      # This ensures that the Spring Boot app starts after the MySQL container
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\nayem\OneDrive\Desktop\docker-volumes:/path/in/container

  mysql-container:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root  # Replace with your desired MySQL root password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: world
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3307:3306    # Map port 3307 on the host to port 3306 in the container
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\nayem\OneDrive\Desktop\docker-volumes:/path/in/container
```

I tried running it differently but still failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many things are wrong here to cover in a single answer.

Let me tackle one by one.

1. Firstly, in your Dockerfile, you copied the src folder, and the pom.xml . Right after that you tried to ran the jar inside the target folder. You have to build the project itself, to generate the jar inside the target folder. To achieve this you want to run ‘mvn package’ inside the folder /home/app.
2. Secondly the database url declared as

   ```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world
   ```

Here the hostname part is set to localhost, which is wrong. As per your docker-compose file, your database hostname should be mysql-container, name of the database service itself. You might expect that you are exposing the port 3306 to host, and from host machine you can connect via localhost. This is fine from host perspective, but not from inside of a container, unless that container is running on the host network.

3. Last but not least, to get up and listening to the port 3306, mysql need some time. in that case, your spring service can try to access the db. declaring only the depends_on clause does not cover it fully. depends_on will start dependent service right after docker container starts the service, on which its depending. But as i said, mysql need some time to listen to the port 3306. What can be done here, you can introduce healthcheck in mysql and in the spring boot service you can say that, it depends on mysql and mysql needed to be healthy.

This how declare that service needed to be healthy and that is the part of the depends_on

```
depends_on:
  mysql-container:
    condition: service_healthy
```

& finally the check, which detetmines, when the service is healthy or not.

```
healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "/usr/bin/mysql --user=webrest-user --password=secret --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
```

https://github.com/ratulSharker/webrest-starter

Above repository already cover all the above aspects of containersation of spring boot application along with mysql.

Comment: Thanks vai. I got it to work somehow, also learnt something new from you.

Comment: If the answer helps you get up running, consider upvoting and accept the answer. It will help others who are seeking for such solution.

Comment: I can't upvote yet, my reputation is low, but I accepted the answer. Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml in your github repo was particularly helpful.