Making database work with a Dockerized Java Spring application
I would like to run my containerized Java Spring application which runs completely fine on my machine (of course, lol).
I have a problem with the JPA database connection.
What stumps me is that this also happens all the same when using just the H2 in-memory database.
Here is the error in the Docker container:
2024-12-02 13:37:39 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:290) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1431) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1502) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at com.rungroop.web.WebApplication.main(WebApplication.java:10) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2024-12-02 13:37:39 
2024-12-02 13:37:39 2024-12-02T12:37:39.141Z ERROR 1 --- [web] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
2024-12-02 13:37:39 2024-12-02T12:37:39.142Z  WARN 1 --- [web] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
2024-12-02 13:37:39 2024-12-02T12:37:39.147Z  INFO 1 --- [web] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-12-02 13:37:39 2024-12-02T12:37:39.163Z  INFO 1 --- [web] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 
2024-12-02 13:37:39 
2024-12-02 13:37:39 Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-12-02 13:37:39 2024-12-02T12:37:39.179Z ERROR 1 --- [web] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2024-12-02 13:37:39 
2024-12-02 13:37:39 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at ...
2024-12-02 13:37:39 Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentWithDefaults(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:362) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-02 13:37:39     ... 37 common frames omitted
2024-12-02 13:37:39 


I have tried using all the help, including several AIs, for no avail so far.
This is my Dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
VOLUME /tmp
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]


This is my docker_compose.yaml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.104:5433/rungroopcourse
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: postgres
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: update
      SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

  db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: postgres3
    ports:
      - "5433:5433"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: rungroopcourse
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres-data:

I have tried using both the containarized database at port 5435 and the native localhost database on port 5433. Both to no avail unfortunately, I always receive the same error. And I've also tried the in-memory database as mentioned.
Here goes my application.properties:
spring.application.name=web
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/rungroopcourse
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.security.user.name=test
spring.security.user.password=test

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# Enable session management
server.servlet.session.persistent=true
server.servlet.session.timeout=30m

# Debugging
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/rungroopcourse



# Specify explicitly the dialect (here for PostgreSQL, adapt for your database)
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Disable Hibernate usage of JDBC metadata
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.boot.allow_jdbc_metadata_access=false

# Database initialization should typically be performed outside of Spring lifecycle
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.sql.init.mode=never

# Allow Hikari Pool suspension
spring.datasource.hikari.allow-pool-suspension=true

Here goes the full updated code in a GitHub repo:
https://github.com/jaroslavchladek/kurabu.info
Kindly please for Your help.
Any idea why this might happen?
Thanks.

Don't use ip addresses to connect, use the service name in this case db to connect. Normally Postgrres runs on port 5432 not 5433 so unless you reconfigured it this won't work (at least not for the inside port).

Does Docker Compose + Spring Boot + Postgres connection include a working setup for you?

@mastermism please check this question and corresponding answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76846511/docker-compose-for-spring-boot-and-mysql-showing-error-failed-to-receive-status/76847314#76847314

This question is similar to: docker-compose for Spring Boot and MySQL showing error: failed to receive status: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Use service name in SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL & default port of postgres db container in docker-compose file as:
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/rungroopcourse
Also default port for postgres is 5432 not 5433, so change port as well.
ports:
    - "5433:5432"

The updated docker-compose file would be:
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/rungroopcourse
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: postgres
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: update
      SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

  db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: postgres3
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: rungroopcourse
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres-data:


Ahmed, another point missed here. The healthcheck of the db service. Service db will take some time to up and running, in that case spring boot service won't be able to connect to db. Please see this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/76847314/2143128
